# Which event is called when iOS app is swiped from app switcher?

Tags: ios, events, event-handling, appdelegate, terminate

I was wondering which event in my AppDelegate is called when I swipe out my running app from within the app switcher? My target iOS is >= 7.0 (i.e. with multitasking support).

Maybe I just don't understand the multitasking paradigm itself... When I swipe out my app from within the app switcher, the app is going to be terminated, right? Or does it continue running in the background?

**EDIT-1:** Why I am asking: During startup of the app, I connect to my Linux game server by plain sockets. I want to disconnect the socket when the app terminates.

**EDIT-2:** I am not sure if I am using background execution. I register my network socket within a run-loop object to asynchronously receive inputs from the server socket. Moreover I have a kind of network service installed that periodically tests for network connectivity. This service is using SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are situations where `applicationWillTerminate:` will be called and sometimes not.

More can be read up from the [Apple documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate:)

Excerpt:

> For apps that do not support background execution or are linked
>   against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is always called when the user
>   quits the app. For apps that support background execution, this method
>   is generally not called when the user quits the app because the app
>   simply moves to the background in that case. However, this method may
>   be called in situations where the app is running in the background
>   (not suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason.

What's interesting to note is that

> After calling this method, the app also posts a
>   UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification notification to give interested
>   objects a chance to respond to the transition.

Comment: I inserted a breakpoint and a log message, but this method is never called in a multitasking (i.e. iOS >= 4.0) environment... The app seems to proceed running in the background after swiping off from the app switcher...

Comment: Are you using background execution in your app? In that case it will only move to the background as mentioned. More precisely, is it okay to share what you are trying to achieve here? There might be alternate solutions to it.

Comment: I have edited the original question to answer your question... Btw. thanks for your help!

Comment: From what I see it does not look like you are using background execution. For more details on background execution you can check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Also would it make sense for you to disconnect your sockets when your application will enter background state and reconnect when it becomes active? In the mean while you could perform finite length background tasks to get any updates using the background execution in iOS.

Comment: thank you - yes i will re-consider the approach you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It is   - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: No this method is not called in a multitask iOS environment, even if I swipe the app off of the app switcher. It seems to proceed running in the background.

Comment: @salocinx I have tested it for ios 9 Beta and this is the one that was called

Comment: Okay it seems that I am using background execution what prevents the method being called... I can't upvote your question until you edit anything. I am sorry...